# Не отображается DocumentView

Tags: android, android-layout

пытаюсь сделать отображение LinarLayout из состояния GONE в видимое анимацией "разворачивания" вниз. На этом Layout лежат кнопка и DocumentView (bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android), последний был выбран только потому, что умеет форматировать текст "по ширине".
Так вот вроде всё сделал, а DocumentView не виден после разворачивания. Если убрать всю анимацию и GONE, а просто запустить Activity, то DocumentView виден и текст в нём есть. Ежели менять GONE -> VISIBLE,то его нет...
Что я делаю не так?

```
<LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/ll_info">
            <com.bluejamesbond.text.DocumentView xmlns:ext="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/bayer_note"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                ext:documentView_antialias="true"
                ext:documentView_textAlignment="justified"
                ext:documentView_textColor="@android:color/white"
                ext:documentView_textFormat="plain"
                ext:documentView_textSize="12dp"
                ext:documentView_text="@string/buyer_note"/>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/button_continue"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="54dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:background="@drawable/button_register"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_arrow_forward_white_24dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/btn_cont_caption"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Войти"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:fontFamily="fonts/SF-UI-Display-Regular.ttf"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_door"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_cont_caption"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

*Update:*

```
        final LinearLayout ll_info = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll_info);

        class scaleAnimation extends Animation {
                    public LinearLayout ll;
                    public int newHeight;

                    public void scaleTopHeight(int height)
                    {
                        newHeight = height;
                    }

                    public void setLayout(LinearLayout layout) {
                        ll = layout;
                    }
                }

                final LinearLayout ll_info = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll_info);

                scaleAnimation h = new scaleAnimation() {
                    @Override
                    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
                        ll.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1
                                ? LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                                : (int)(newHeight * interpolatedTime);
                        ll.requestLayout();
                    }
                };
                h.setDuration(300);
                h.setLayout(ll_info);
        ll_info.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ll_info.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(((LinearLayout)ll_info.getParent()).getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(((LinearLayout)ll_info.getParent()).getHeight(), View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
                h.scaleTopHeight(ll_info.getMeasuredHeight());
        ll_info.getLayoutParams().height=1;
                ll_info.startAnimation(h);
```

Comment: Попробуйте что-то типа `invalidate()` вызвать - может он там так сделан, что просто не прорисовывается после изменения видимости

Comment: думаю что проблема коде, покажите анимацию и изменения видимости после

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei добавил в основной вопрос

Comment: очень интересная структура анимации это можно сделай гораздо проще, но не суть. 
Те после анимации у вас видны все элементы, кроме DocumentView ?

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei ага... и высота "выезжания" равна высоте остальных без DocumentView. Пробовал заменить DV на TextView, результат тот же. <br>а проще это как?